# Configure Microsoft Office 365 Single Sign-On (SSO) with OpenEMR

Tags: php

What are the steps to configure Microsoft Office 365 Single Sign-On (SSO) with OpenEMR?

I want to use Microsoft Office 365 Single Sign-On (SSO) with OpenEMR. I am currently using OpenEMR v6.0.0 with PHP version 7.4.9 and MySQL version 5.7.32 on Windows 10.

Comment: You should ask this question on openemr's support site because if openerm supports azure ad authentication, then it is not a programming task you face and if it does not support it, then you can make a feature request there. Implementing azure ad authentication from scratch is not an easy thing to do and is way more complex we can cover in a single SO answer.